# Adding custom control with a collection property to a SharePoint Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint, custom-controls

I have created a custom control with a collection property per the example on [How do you build an ASP.NET custom control with a collection property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123616/how-do-you-build-an-asp-net-custom-control-with-a-collection-property)

When the control is added to a common ASP.Net aspx page it works as expected. However, when added to a Page Layout in Sharepoint the following error is thrown:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.CollectionBuilder' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[mytypes.mytype]'.

The code is pretty much identical to the code provided by the example shown in the link above. I do not think the fault lies in the control as it works fine in a plain web project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can use generic lists in sharepoint. Use an ArrayList or customised List collection instead (use asp:ListItem as an exampe, it has its own collection type)

```
[ParseChildren(true, "Names")]
public class MyControl : Control {
    private List<PersonName> names;
    public MyControl() {
        names = new List<PersonName>();
    }
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    public List<PersonName> Names {
        get { return this.names; }
    }
}
public class PersonName {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ahh i see the problem now, it is not to do with the generic list, it is because of the way you are doing the initialization.

1. Create a private variable to hold the list `private List<PersonName> names;`
2. Ensure that the property does not have a setter

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't have the desired effect.
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.CollectionBuilder' to type 'System.Collections.ArrayList'

Comment: Many thanks. Any ideas as to why it works if a setter is omitted?